# Radio button value not being returned correctly through JS when hidden

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

So what I am trying to do is have the user select a radio button, click next, then be taken to a different view depending on what they selected.

TestApp.app

```
<aura:application >
  <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.jquery}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}" />
  <aura:attribute name="radiochoice" type="Integer" default="0"/>
  <aura:attribute name="stage" type="Integer" default="0" />
  <aura:if isTrue="{!v.stage == 0}">
    <fieldset class="slds-form-element">
      <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="select-01"> </label>
      <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <label class="slds-radio">
          <input type="radio" name="options" value="1" />
          <span class="slds-radio--faux"></span>
          <span class="slds-form-element__label">Choice 1</span>
        </label>
        <label class="slds-radio">
          <input type="radio" name="options" value="2" />
          <span class="slds-radio--faux"></span>
          <span class="slds-form-element__label">Choice 2</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <ui:button  buttonTitle="Click to check radiobutton" class="button" label="Check" press="{!c.getInput}"/>
  </aura:if>
  <p>{!v.radiochoice}</p>
  <aura:if isTrue="{!v.stage == 1}">
    <ui:button  buttonTitle="Click to go back" class="button" label="Back" press="{!c.back}"/>
  </aura:if>
</aura:application>
```

TestAppController.js

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    },

  getInput: function(cmp, evt) {
        console.log(document.querySelector('input[name="options"]:checked').value);
    cmp.set("v.radiochoice", $("input[name='options']:checked").val());
            cmp.set("v.stage", 1);
  },
    back : function(cmp, evt) {
        cmp.set("v.stage", 0);
    }
})
```

When I select a value I should be sent to the next page and shown the value of the radio button I selected.
Without LockerService, it seems to work fine.
[Without LockerService](https://i.imgur.com/BoG44oT.gifv)

When I enable LockerService, it seems to always fetch whatever the first selected value was.
[With LockerService](https://i.imgur.com/tEKYjUO.gifv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely incorrect behavior, and would appear to be a bug in the way locker service wraps elements to protect access. I opened an internal bug W-3203877 and will try to verify in the next day.

If you can open a case, please do, and let them know the bug number.

Comment: Could this be related to the issue where binding to properties of arrays/objects gets stuck on the first value? Despite the fact that it's happening at the level of mock DOM nodes it's similar behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in the Spring '17 major release. Thanks for the great repro!